# use inner query query order sequence in outer query result

Tags: mysql

I have two  tables- ALPHA & BETA. I am using the result of a query on BETA for an outer query on ALPHA.

```
SELECT  a,b 
FROM    alpha 
WHERE   a IN(
    SELECT a 
    FROM   beta 
    WHERE  some_condition 
    ORDER  BY c DESC
);
```

Now my problem is that i need to maintain the `DESC ORDER` in the final result but since i dont have access to `c` in table `alpha`,i am not able to do display result in desired oder.

Is there any way to use the inner query order sequence in outer query. I cannot change the structure of either of the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change the structure of the table just to allow to order the row, you just need to `JOIN` the tables so you can access the columns from the other table and preserve the `ORDER`.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT al.a, al.b
FROM    alpha al
        INNER JOIN Beta be
            ON al.a = be.a
WHERE   be. -- some condition
ORDER   BY be.c DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The order by clause in sub query will not have any effect for your scenario.

Instead of subquery framework, what you need is a join framework. you need to join alpha and beta table using a common field, after the join is created all columns from alpha and beta tables are available and sorting is then easy.

i have tried to change your query in join framework.
SELECT alpha.a,b 
FROM alpha inner join beta on 
alpha.[somefield] = beta.[somefield] 
WHERE some_condition
ORDER BY beta.c DESC;